# How to convert spark RDD to mahout DRM?

Tags: apache-spark, mahout, alluxio

I am fetching data from Alluxio in Mahout using sc.textFile(), but it is spark RDD. My program further uses this spark RDD as Mahout DRM, therefore I needed to convert RDD to DRM. So my current code remains stable.

Answer (score 2):

An Apache Mahout DRM can be created from an Apache Spark RDD in the following steps:

1. Convert each row of the RDD into a Mahout Vector
2. Zip the RDD with an Index (and swap so the tuple is of form `(Long, Vector)`
3. Wrap the RDD with a DRM.

Consider the following Example Code:

```
val rddA = sc.parallelize(Array((1.0, 2.0, 3.0),
            ( 2.0, 3.0, 4.0),
            ( 4.0, 5.0, 6.0)))

val drmRddA: DrmRdd[Long] = rddA.map(a => new DenseVector(a))
                 .zipWithIndex()
                 .map(t => (t._2, t._1))

val drmA = drmWrap(rdd= drmRddA)
```

Source /more info/ Shameless Self Promotion (toward the bottom): [my Blog](https://rawkintrevo.org/2016/10/13/deep-magic-volume2-absurdly-large-ols-with-apache-mahout/)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with converting data is often that Mahout uses integers to reference row and column numbers of a general matrix but data usually has its own row and column keys, which are string ids of some sort.

Mahout has an object called an `IndexedDatasetSpark` which preserves the ids in `BiMaps` (actually `BiDictionaries`) but also creates a Mahout DRM. The benefit being that the dictionaries will convert the integers for row and columns back into your IDs after the math is done.

If you have an RDD[String, String] of elements for a matrix this will do the conversion. If you have an array of rows, you may be able to start from this to code your own conversion.

https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/sparkbindings/indexeddataset/IndexedDatasetSpark.scala#L75

Comment: For an example of how to transform an RDD into an IDS please see
[this gist](https://gist.github.com/rawkintrevo/c1bb00896263bdc067ddcd8299f4794c)